# Request method 'POST' not supported when trying to upload file

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am new to Development and Spring Boot..
I would like to make an app that uploads a file and shows the hash of it
I have managed to create a basic app but when I try to do a form and "POST"
the file I get the following error on the STS console : 
Request method 'POST' not supported
Could you please help?
This is my code of the controller:

```
package controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class FileUploadController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void downloadFile(@RequestParam(value="file") String file){

    }

}
```

Comment: Where is your form ?

Comment: You mentioned upload but code is for download. What is really sent? do you have form? or ajax? Do you have headers?

Comment: "You mentioned upload but code is for download. What is really sent? do you have form? or ajax? Do you have headers?" I don`t understand..I followed the examples on You mentioned upload but code is for download. What is really sent? do you have form? or ajax? Do you have headers? Thank you!

Comment: Hi, I getting another error now....Parameter 0 of constructor in com.boot.test9.FileUploadController required a bean of type 'com.boot.test9.StorageService' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.boot.test9.StorageService' in your configuration. Please help...?

Answer (score 0):

```
@PostMapping("/")
public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
        RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

    storageService.store(file);
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message",
            "You successfully uploaded " + file.getOriginalFilename() + "!");

    return "redirect:/";
}



<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/">
        <table>
            <tr><td>File to upload:</td><td><input type="file" name="file" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></td></tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: Hi,You tool it from Spring right? https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/ that is exactly what I did and it does not work...

Comment: Why you have 2 same @RequestMapping("/") ?

Comment: In your sample you have RequestMapping one on top if the class and one on the method

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it.
I have removed the storage service and just posted a redirect to test.html
And it works ok
I just need to know how to manipulate this a file and return the hash valuse of it to the web app

```
@PostMapping("/")
    public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
            RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {



    return "redirect:/test.html";

    }
```

Thank you guys!